# Rewriting grep in C++

Tags: c++, vector, grep

So I'm trying to write a progam that performs the same task as grep. In the end I want a program that takes four arguments, the second being what to search for, the third being the input file and the fourth being the output file. I think I've got a good grasp on how to go about it, but as usual the theory come easy and the actual programming I get all confused. Basically where I'm at now I've got the file in and I'm trying to search it and get the all of the lines that contain what I'm searching for, as well as the line of that number.

I want to use a vector to achieve this task. I am not entirely sure how to go about it. Would it be easier to go through and add each line to the vector individually and then go through and pick out those that have the desired string in them and use thier array location as the line number?  I would like to think there is a way of only adding those lines to the vector which contain the desired string, but then I'm not sure how to get the line number. I've started a couple times and then erased what I ahd when I realized it was all wrong.

This is where I'm at now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

// validate the command line info
if( argc < 2 ) {
    cout << "Error: Incorrect number of command line arguments\n"
            "Usage: grep\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//Declare the arguments of the array
string query = argv[1]; 
string inputFileName = argv[2];
string outputFileName = argv [3];

// Validate that the file is there and open it
ifstream infile( inputFileName );
if( !infile ) {
    cout << "Error: failed to open <" << inputFileName << ">\n"
            "Check filename, path, or it doesn't exist.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

else{
vector<string> queries;


}

}

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you find something easier such as solving the Poincaré conjecture or Riemann hypothesis? Have you actually _seen_ the code for regular expression handling? :-)

Comment: Re: *#include <regex.h>*

Most of the complexity of grep is in the above. The original author of `grep` wrote that part too. 

What you're writing is just the trivial shell around the regex API. Try harder. :)

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. :) Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a vector. It seems to me you should just go through the input file a line at a time using std::getline, try to match each one against the regex, and output the lines that succeed immediately.

Comment: I see, I'm really new to using output files as well, and was planning on doing some reading on them tonight. Would it be easy to put them all into an output file using this method? Also, using this method how would I save what line the numbers to keep them with the line I'm printing. Just a loop that and use the iterator as the line number?

Comment: @Sh0gun Yeah, outputting to a file is no different whether you're doing it from a `vector<string>` you've filled up or outputting each line directly after it matches. To get line numbers you'll have a counter to keep track of what line number you're processing, and when a line matches you'll just use the value of that counter as the line number.

Comment: @Sh0gun Also, it sounds like you might need to work up to the final program. I suggest you write a program that just echoes an input file to an output file line by line. Then modify it to include line numbers. then modify it again to only output lines that fit some condition, such as an even line number. Then change the condition to be a check if the line matches the regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I did it that way and it was much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the complexity with implementing a complete grep would be handling the dozens of flags to modify how it works. A simplified version that doesn't try to support those and just searches a set of files for a specified pattern can be pretty simple. A C++11 version looks roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

class line {
    std::string data;
public:
    operator std::string() const { return data; }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        return std::getline(is, l.data);
    }
};

void process(std::regex const &pattern, std::istream &file) {
    typedef std::istream_iterator<line> in;
    typedef std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out;

    std::copy_if(in(file), 
                in(), 
                out(std::cout, "\n"), 
                [&](std::string const &s) {return std::regex_search(s, pattern);});
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: grep <pattern> [file specification]";
        return 1;
    }

    std::regex pattern(argv[1], std::regex::nosubs | std::regex::optimize);

    if (argc < 3)
        process(pattern, std::cin);
    else
        for (int i=2; i<argc; ++i) {
            std::ifstream infile(argv[i]);
            std::cout << "\t-- " << argv[i] << " --\n";
            process(pattern, infile);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

On Unix-like systems, you don't have to do anything special to build this. On Windows, you'll want to link with the compiler-supplied object file that handles globbing (e.g., `setargv.obj`, with MS VC++).